# Proving a set is not an open ball

Tags: metric-spaces

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, $x\in X$ and $r>0$. The set $$B(x,r)=\{y\in X: d(x,y)<r \}$$ is called an open ball centered at $x$ and radius $r$.

In the usual metric space, let $x=1$, then $(0.5, 1.5)$ is an open ball of  radius $r=0.5$ centered at $x=1$.
Now, I want to show that $(0.5, 1.5)\cup (5,7)$ is not an open ball of radius $r>0$  centered at $x=1$.
My steps are:

1. First, an open ball of radius $r>0$ centered at $x=1$ is an open interval $(1-r,1+r)$.
2. Then I need show $(0.5, 1.5)\cup (5,7)\neq (1-r,1+r)$. To do that, I consider some cases, i.e.
   (i) if $0<r<1$, then there exists $6\in  (0.5, 1.5)\cup (5,7)$, but $6\notin (1-r,1+r)$.
   (ii) if $r=1$,then $(1-r,1+r)=(0,2)\nsubseteq (0.5, 1.5)\cup (5,7)$.
   (iii) if $r>1$ then there exists $1-\frac{r}{2}\le 0$ such that $1-\frac{r}{2}\in (1-r,1+r)$ but $1-\frac{r}{2}\notin (0.5, 1.5)\cup (5,7)$.
   From (i)-(iii), I get $(0.5, 1.5)\cup (5,7)\neq (1-r,1+r)$.

Are my steps above correct?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Open balls are connected sets in the set of real numbers.

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia I think at this stage OP has not yet learned about connected spaces. Simpler arguments would be more helpful.

Comment: @NewB yes, I have not yet learned about connected spaces.

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia so, my attempt is not correct?

Comment: Your proof seems perfectly fine.

Comment: What is the 'usual' metric space?

Comment: @Poseidaan it is a metric space $(\mathbb{R},d)$ with $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: There is a small typo in step (ii). If $r=1$, then $(1-r,1+r) = (0,2)$ instead of $(0,1)$.

Comment: @stange thanks for the correction, I have edited it.